# Silverlight 4 page authentication attribute

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

In Asp.net MVC you can do:

```
[Authorize]
public class someController{}
```

Is there a way you can do this in silverlight pages? I saw a guy do this with his own code [here](http://www.silverlight-travel.com/blog/2009/06/24/displaying-a-login-dialog-based-on-page-attributes-in-silverlight-3/). Is there anything built in silverlight like this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that give a decent overview of using ASP.NET Membership from within Silverlight:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Leveraging-the-ASP.NET-Membership-in-Silverlight.aspx

Comment: I know this. I have authentication done already, I just need something that asp.net mvc has done for pages, in a silverlight business app with pages.